# mat-date-range-picker Behind the modal

Tags: html, angular

i open modal and within the modal, there is a date input using a calendar picker. The date input window opens below the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-bs-target="#addEmployeeModal">
                            + Add New
                          </button>

.......

    <div class="modal modal-xl center" id="updateEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="employeeEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 style="font-weight: bold" class="modal-bs-title" id="updateEmployeeModalLabel">Edit Tasks</h1>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            .........................

            <div class="form-group" >
                        <mat-form-field class="custom-form-field">
                            <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="datepicker" > 
                                <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" > 
                                <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" > 
                            </mat-date-range-input> 
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle> 
                            <mat-date-range-picker  #datepicker></mat-date-range-picker>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx1MD.png)

The date input window opens below the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with 'z-index'?

```
 <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="datepicker" > 
     <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" style="z-index: 1;"> 
     <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" style="z-index: 1;"> 
 </mat-date-range-input>
```

If is not in input try to add z-index in `mat-date-range-input` or inspect your code in browser to find the correct html class.
Don't know if this can fix your code, maybe a stackblitz page can help us to try this